# How can i pass values to the method of class?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this class

```
    class Registration {

        function registration() {
            print_r($_REQUEST);

            $fname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fname']));
            $lname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lname']));
        }

$obj_reg = new registration();
    }
```

I am getting the values from `$.post` method of jquery ,here its how

```
sUrl='http://localhost/Temp/registration.php'
tsQueryStr='f_name=rjseh&l_name=rjseh&badge_name=rjseh';


    $.post(sUrl,tsQueryStr, function(data){
            alert(data);

        });
```

But these values are not printing inside class method
I am using core-php

please help,

Comment: What is the content of `registration.php`? Is `registration()` ever invoked on a `Registration` instance?

Comment: inside `registration.php` -> the file above itself.

Comment: Your variable names are different? you are sending `f_name` while accessing `fname` in the class?

IF `print_r($_REQUEST);` isn't printing anything it means this function isn't called properly.

Comment: that is no matter bcoz i am printing `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Where are you initializing the class object? `Registration()` is a constructor which could only be called once object is declared? I can't see object declaration in your `Registration.php`

Comment: updated the body of question please see above.

Comment: Can you check on firebug if the ajax request is sent successfully??

Comment: this is response in firebug `POST:http://localhost/MRS/registration/registration.php 200 OK 103ms`

Comment: Please note that I have changed the Constructor name with capital R.

Comment: yaa got it,but suppose i have two methods and i dont want to pass these values to constructor then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP should be something like:

```
class Registration {

    function registration() {
        print_r($_REQUEST);

        $fname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fname']));
        $lname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lname']));
    }
}

$obj_reg = new Registration();
$obj_reg->registration();
```

Comment: but suppose i have two methods and i dont want to pass these values to constructor then?

Comment: If you keep accessing them from $_POST, you don't have to pass the values to the constructor anyway, since $_POST is global. Otherwise you can do something like: `$_POST['some_param'] ? $obj_reg->method1($_POST) : $obj_reg->method2($_POST);`. If I misunderstood you and this doesn't help, just post another message with the code and I'll be able to explain better.